# How to use os.time () to know current time in script?

Tags: time, lua

Basically, How can I use `os.time()` and `os.difftime()` or possibly `os.clock()` to find out my current time that it has been running at a certain part of the script.

So at 10 minutes I am trying to run a command and at 20 mins I am trying to run another command all the way up to 40 mins in 10 min intervals and then I'm trying to reset back to 0 and restart.

Any ideas?

Comment: `os.time()` returns number of seconds passed from some fixed date.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem? It's all described in the Lua reference manual.
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.time

`os.time([table])`, if called without an argument returns the current time.

`os.difftime(t2, t1)` returns the time difference t2-t1 in seconds.

So simply store your start time and then frequently check if the time difference is >= 600. then reset your start time and do the same again.

You can also use os.clock()

In any case you have to stop what you are doing from time to time and check if the time has come to run your function. So you have to split your sequential code into interruptable bits. If you don't do anything between those 10 minute marks you can simply check the time in a simple loop.

There are plenty of Lua libraries (e.g. wxLua) that provide convenient timer and timer event functions. If you don't want to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your script store initial time use that value later to find time since script started, eg:

```
start_time = os.time()

function sleep(n)  -- seconds
  local t0 = os.clock()
  while os.clock() - t0 <= n do end
end

-- Write script logic here...
-- ...
sleep(5)
-- ...
-- You can later find how much time passed since beginning of execution by calling os.time() again
print(os.time()-start_time.." seconds since start of script execution...")
```